# How to change my exe icon dynamically while taking setup in vb6

Tags: vb6

I have a single exe file. I have to take multiple setup with same exe by changing with different icon. Is it possible how to change my exe icon dynamically while taking setup?.Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, and I don't have enough karma to comment and ask for clarification.

If you're looking to change the *application* icon that appears in the titlebar at top left of your app window(s), see this article from Microsoft:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259673

If you're trying to change the desktop icon of a shortcut at runtime, there's a library you can use called iShellLink that really simplifies this process. You can find it here:

http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Type_Libraries/ShellLink/article.asp